# How do I display HTML in ASP.NET MVC 2?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2

I am writting an application to store HTML pages in a database. I would like to have a "preview" button to show the page.

What is the best way to display the HTML page on a MVC 2 view page? Are there any web page viewers that work with MVC?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

The best web page viewer I've seen is Google Chrome.

If you're storing HTML in the database, then it's presumably just going to be a string. Therefore, if you're doing a preview box, why not do it in a [lightbox](http://colorpowered.com/colorbox/), like Colorbox?

Comment: so you are saying I sould accept answers that I don't believe are correct for my situation.

Comment: If they're not correct for your situation, then you comment on them like you've just done, **not abandon them**! That's how the community works - question -> answer -> feedback -> update question / refine answer -> repeat -> accepted. It ain't rocket science!

Answer (score 0):

If the HTML stored in the database is a complete page, I would say put it in either a separate frame, or just put it in an iframe on the page.

You could do this by having a controller action and view that simply renders the html from the database, then use that as the source for you frame/iframe.